# Are there any ways to control the speed of AWS SQS

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-sqs

I wonder if there are any config that help control the throught put of SQS queue. For example, limit the queue to only send 30 requests/sec.

Comment: Queues don't "send requests," so it isn't really clear what you are trying to accomplish.  Can you clarify?

Comment: as @Michael-sqlbot says queues receive messages, store them and then they are polled to remove the messages.  You need to think about how the polling is done, the process that gets the messages is where the rate of consumption can be limited